# String replace in vim: Why does %s/foo/bar work?

Tags: regex, vi

`:%s/foo/bar/g`

This vim command has saved me lots of time.  But today I accidentally typed

`:%s/foo/bar` without the global (g) ending and it worked anyway!  I was very confused.  What's going on?  Is it better to use the `/g` and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work even if you dont specify /g but it replaces only first occurrence of match and not the second and consecutive occurrences in the file.

Comment: It "works" but it does something different. If you only have one match on each line, the `/g` is superflouous, of course.

Comment: Realized this was an impulsive question I could have looked up easily.  Please close the question.  If I can close it myself, I will do so

Answer (score 2):

`%s/foo/bar/g` runs `s/foo/bar/g` for each line. This replaces all instances of `foo` by `bar`.

`%s/foo/bar` runs `s/foo/bar` for each line. This replaces the first instance of `foo` by `bar`.

Suppose your file consists of

```
foo foo foo
foo foo foo
foo foo foo
```

Then `%s/foo/bar/g` turns it into

```
bar bar bar
bar bar bar
bar bar bar
```

But `%s/foo/bar` turns it into

```
bar foo foo
bar foo foo
bar foo foo
```